# R language the result will be NA or different after using as.Date

Tags: r

I am doing the EDA Case Study and I face a date converting issue. 
The number will be different after using as.Date function.

```
dates <- pm0$Date
> str(dates)
 int [1:1304287] 20120101 20120104 20120107 20120110 20120113 20120116 20120119 20120122 20120125 20120128 ...

dates <- as.Date(as.character(dates), "%y%m%d")
> str(dates)
 Date[1:1304287], format: "2020-12-01" "2020-12-01" "2020-12-01" "2020-12-01" "2020-12-01" ...

## the date is changed from 20120101 to 20201201 and all the results are the same

## If i modify the code to be (format = "%y-%m-%d") the result will be NA
```

Answer (score 5):

The `%y` specifies for 2 digit year, we need `%Y` for 4 digit year.

```
as.Date("20120101", "%Y%m%d")
#[1] "2012-01-01"
```

If we do `%y`, it matches the first two digits `20` as year, and prefix with `20` as by default, it is appending the current era, then the month matches the "12" and day the next 01, leaving the last 01 out

```
as.Date("20120101", "%y%m%d")
#[1] "2020-12-01"
```

It is also documented in the `?strptime`

> %y
>   Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.
>
> %Y
>   Year with century. Note that whereas there was no zero in the original Gregorian calendar, ISO 8601:2004 defines it to be valid (interpreted as 1BC): see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year). Note that the standards also say that years before 1582 in its calendar should only be used with agreement of the parties involved.

Though, the `format` is not documented in `?as.Date`, it gives a link to `strptime` to check for `format`

> format
>   character string. If not specified, it will try tryFormats one by one on the first non-NA element, and give an error if none works. Otherwise, the processing is via strptime.